# acces cookie at children directorie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

In www.my-domain.com/test/section/file.php I'm traying to access to and update a cookie that I set in www.my-domain/test/index.php .

I set the cookie with path: '/' and domain: '.my-domain.com' , and when I examine them it show in /my-domain.com/test . Next, I can access to the content of the cookie in section/file.php, but when I update the cookie, it create a new cookie with the same name at /my-domain.com/test/section.

The question is: Can I write a cookie in my-domain.com/test/section/file.php with the path /www.my-domain.com/test/?

I use this to set the cookie in both directions:

```
var cart_cookie_json = $.cookie("cookie_cart"); # read the cookie
var cart = JSON.parse(cart_cookie_json); #decode cookie
   ####cart is an array, I add some elements...
cart_cookie_json = JSON.stringify(cart); #encode
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie("cart", cart_cookie_json, { expires: date }, {path: '/'},{domain: '.jczlabs.com'});
```

Comment: can you show the code you are using to update/create

Answer (score 0):

I found mi error: I only need to set path: '/test/' wherever I set or update the cookie.
WARNING: for javaScript is not the same '/test' than '/test/'